# azure devops: A user can't see the repo, another user in the same group with the same permissions can. Why is this?

Tags: azure-devops

We have 15+ users in a Contributors group that can view and modify the repos in Azure DevOps just fine. I am trying to add another user, user Z, to be able to view and modify the repos. I add user Z under the Contributors group successfully (Z is an AAD user). Z user then logs in to Azure DevOps but cannot see the repos, although user Z has read only access to other parts of Azure Devops, including group permissions. The Repos menu link on the left doesn't show up at all for user Z.

I have checked the repro permissions specifically and the Contributors group is one of the allowed groups. All the other users can access the repros successfully, but not user Z.

Any ideas why this may be? I've removed and readded user Z multiple times. I've removed other un-need users from the Contributors group (in case there is a limit of users), but still no success.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have enough licences for these users? You need basic licenses after 5 person for each person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the users, who don't have access to the repo, don't have Basic User License of Azure Devops. First 5 basic user license is free but after that, you need to buy license which costs 6$/month.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Comment: It was a license issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should have enough licenses for ALL users. You can only get 5 free licenses for free and after that you need to buy them.
Thanks

Comment: It depends on the currency you are using, in USD it is $6 per month